# Message: Undefined index: when getting column name (two table with the same column) CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get the data from two tables with the same column name. I already put some aliases in the column name. But it doesn't work.

***Controller***

```
public function price_master_list(){

    $result['mediacat'] = $this->em->getmedia_with_category();
    $this->load->view('price_master_list',$result);
}
```

***Model***

```
function getmedia_with_category(){
    $query2 = $this->db->select('*','m.name as `catname`', false)->from('media as m')->join('media_category as c', 'c.media_id = m.id')->where('m.delete_flag','1')->get();
    $response = $query2->result_array();
    return $response;
}
```

***View***

```
<?php foreach($mediacat as $medcat){ ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $medcat['catname']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CI select accepts only two params, you passed three.

Try this:

```
function getmedia_with_category(){
    $query2 = $this->db->select('m.*,c.name as catname', false)->from('media as m')->join('media_category as c', 'c.media_id = m.id')->where('m.delete_flag','1')->get();
    $response = $query2->result_array();
    return $response;
}
```